# Datatable pagination not showing using serverSide

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using JQuery Datatable to display data from database and everything works well  except the pagination numbers are not showing and I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Here is the code Im using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row filter-row">
    ____Filter_FORM__
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 card-box">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped custom-table datatable" id="productTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><strong>Référence</strong> </th>
                        <th style="width:30%;"><strong>Article</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Catégorie</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Fournisseur</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Prix Unitaire</strong></th>
                        <th><strong>Unité</strong></th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:20%;"><strong>Action</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
fill_datatable()
function fill_datatable(filter_supplier='', filter_category=''){
    var dataTable = $('#productTable').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true, 
        "order" : [],
        "searching" : false,
        "ajax" : {
            url: `ajax/products/list.php`,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                filter_supplier: filter_supplier, 
                filter_category : filter_category,
            }
        }
    });
}

$("#filter_data").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var filter_supplier = $("#filter_supplier").val();
    var filter_category = $("#filter_category").val();

    if(filter_supplier != '0' && filter_category !=  '0' ){
        $('#productTable').DataTable().destroy()
        fill_datatable(filter_supplier, filter_category)
    }else{
        
        $('#productTable').DataTable().destroy()
        fill_datatable()
    }

})
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$column = array('reference', 'designation' ,'category_id' , 'supplier_id', 'unity_price', 'unity');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` ";

if(isset($_POST['filter_supplier'], $_POST['filter_category'])){

    if($_POST['filter_supplier'] != '0' && $_POST['filter_category'] != '0')
    {
        $query .= ' 
            WHERE supplier_id = "'.$_POST['filter_supplier'].'" AND category_id = "'.$_POST['filter_category'].'"
        ';
    }
    else if($_POST['filter_supplier'] == '0' && $_POST['filter_category'] != '0')
    {
        $query .= ' WHERE  category_id = "'.$_POST['filter_category'].'" ';
    }
    else if($_POST['filter_supplier'] != '0' && $_POST['filter_category'] == '0')
    {
        $query .= '  WHERE supplier_id = "'.$_POST['filter_supplier'].'" ';
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
    $query .= ' ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' ' .$_POST['order']['0']['dir']. ' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY reference ASC';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST['length'] != -1)
{
    $query1 = ' LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] .', ' . $_POST['length'] ;
}

$statement = $PDO->prepare($query);

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $PDO->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

if($statement->rowCount() != 0)
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {

        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row['reference'];
        $sub_array[] = $row['designation'];
        $sub_array[] = Utils::categoryName($row['category_id']);
        $sub_array[] = Utils::getSupplierName($row['supplier_id']);
        $sub_array[] = $row['unity_price'];        
        $sub_array[] = $row['unity'];
        $sub_array[] = '
            <div class="dropdown pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class="edit_product" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i> Modifier</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="delete_product" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Supprimer</a></li>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
        ';
        
        $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
}else{
    $sub_array = array('','','','','','','');
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}


function count_all_data($connect)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `products` ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
    'draw'              => intval($_POST['draw']),
    'recordsTotal'      => count_all_data($PDO),
    'recordsFiltered'   => $number_filter_row,
    'data'              => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

**SCREENSHOT**
Below a screenshot demonstrating the issue Im facing.

[image]

What I'm missing in my code ?
Thank you

**UPDATE (json response)**

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1095,
  "recordsFiltered": 0,
  "data": [
    [
      "PR-00001",
      "5L COLLE FLOMBO",
      "Divers",
      "Ets Rami",
      "0.00",
      null,
      "\r\n            
<div class=\"dropdown pull-right\">\r\n                
                  <a href=\"#\" class=\"action-icon dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
                        <i class=\"fa fa-ellipsis-v\"></i>
                  </a>\r\n                
                  <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">\r\n  
                        <li><a href=\"#\" class=\"edit_product\" data-id=\"2\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil m-r-5\"></i> Modifier</a></li>\r\n  
                        <li><a href=\"#\" class=\"delete_product\" data-id=\"2\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o m-r-5\"></i> Supprimer</a></li>\r\n                \r\n                </ul>\r\n            
            </div>\r\n        "

    ],
    [
      "PR-00002",
      "ACIDE 1L",
      "Divers",
      "ECOTRA",
      "0.00",
      null,
      "\r\n
            <div class=\"dropdown pull-right\">\r\n                
                  <a href=\"#\" class=\"action-icon dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">
                        <i class=\"fa fa-ellipsis-v\"></i>
                  </a>\r\n                
                  <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">\r\n  
                        <li><a href=\"#\" class=\"edit_product\" data-id=\"2\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil m-r-5\"></i> Modifier</a></li>\r\n  
                        <li><a href=\"#\" class=\"delete_product\" data-id=\"2\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o m-r-5\"></i> Supprimer</a></li>\r\n                \r\n                </ul>\r\n            
            </div>\r\n        "
    ],
 .... etc
}
```

** POST DATA **

```
draw: 1
columns[0][data]: 0
columns[0][name]: 
columns[0][searchable]: true
columns[0][orderable]: true
columns[0][search][value]: 
columns[0][search][regex]: false
columns[1][data]: 1
columns[1][name]: 
columns[1][searchable]: true
columns[1][orderable]: true
columns[1][search][value]: 
columns[1][search][regex]: false
columns[2][data]: 2
columns[2][name]: 
columns[2][searchable]: true
columns[2][orderable]: true
columns[2][search][value]: 
columns[2][search][regex]: false
columns[3][data]: 3
columns[3][name]: 
columns[3][searchable]: true
columns[3][orderable]: true
columns[3][search][value]: 
columns[3][search][regex]: false
columns[4][data]: 4
columns[4][name]: 
columns[4][searchable]: true
columns[4][orderable]: true
columns[4][search][value]: 
columns[4][search][regex]: false
columns[5][data]: 5
columns[5][name]: 
columns[5][searchable]: true
columns[5][orderable]: true
columns[5][search][value]: 
columns[5][search][regex]: false
columns[6][data]: 6
columns[6][name]: 
columns[6][searchable]: true
columns[6][orderable]: true
columns[6][search][value]: 
columns[6][search][regex]: false
start: 0
length: 10
search[value]: 
search[regex]: false
filter_supplier: 
filter_category:
```

Comment: What do you get if you just load the PHP file? If your site is example.com by navigating to: `https://example.com/ajax/products/list.phphisphpfile.php`

Comment: There is no issue with simple php file. the pagination are displayed.

Comment: Can you show us the raw text of the response JSON?

Comment: Are you passing the required pagination information back from the server to the browser in the response JSON? It looks as if you are not doing that, based on the "Affichage de 0 à 0 sur 0 entrées..." message in your screenshot. See the "Returned data" and "Example data" sections from [the documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). It does look as if your PHP code is trying to handle the data - but it does not appear to be added to the JSON response correctly (as far as I can tell, without seeing the JSON).

Comment: I just updated my question and added POST DATA and json response

Comment: Thank you for the updates. The JSON in the question is not valid. Even though it contains `\r\n` for newlines in the final element of each array, that text also contains carriage returns, which makes the JSON invalid (the string is physically split across multiple lines). Is this actually how the JSON is structured in the response? (I don't think this is the underlying problem, though.)

Comment: Thank you sir. I just solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved Thanks to @andrewJames Hints

I Changed

```
'recordsFiltered'   =>$number_filter_row,
```

To:

```
'recordsFiltered'   =>count_all_data($PDO),
```